# Implementing SSL on Windows using WinAPI

Tags: c, sockets, ssl, winapi

I want to implement SSL into my socket application using the Windows API. However, it seems that there are two different SSL APIs, namely `SChannel` (for example [InitSecurityInterfaceW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sspi/nf-sspi-initsecurityinterfacew)) and the [SSL provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-ssl-provider-functions) belong to CNG (Cryptography Next Generation). I'm not sure what's the difference between the two, and which one I should use to implement SSL. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CNG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-features): One of the key value propositions of CNG is cryptographic agility, sometimes called cryptographic agnosticism. Converting implementation of protocols like Secure Sockets Layer protocol (SSL) or transport layer security (TLS), CMS (S/MIME), IPsec, Kerberos, and so on, to CNG, however, was required to make this ability valuable.

[Schannel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/what-s-new-in-tls-ssl-schannel-ssp-overview): Schannel is a Security Support Provider (SSP) that implements the SSL, TLS and DTLS Internet standard authentication protocols.

As far as I'm concerned, if you want to implement SSL, you could choose the `Schannel`. CNG is designed to be extensible at many levels.